# MVC Core 3.1 and Vue/Axios Posting Null Values

Tags: vue.js, axios, asp.net-core-mvc

I am having issues getting ASP.Net MVC Core 3.1 to post data to the `Create` controller method.  Can someone tell me what I am missing? My code is hitting the break point in the `Create` controller method but the parameter is always null.
Ideally I would like to send the form data as JSON and have JSON.Net convert it to an object.  The source I am currently working on is at: https://github.com/encouragingapps/DebtRefresh.

Here is my controller code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DebtRefresh.WebUI.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace DebtRefresh.WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class CreditCardController : Controller 
    {
        // GET: CreditCard
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // GET: CreditCard/Details/5
        //public ActionResult Details(int id)
        //{
        //    return View();
        //}

        // GET: CreditCard/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: CreditCard/Create
        [HttpPost]        
        public ActionResult Create([FromBody]String CardVendor)
        {
            try
            {

                String card;
                card = CardVendor;


                // THIS CODE ALWAYS RETURNS NULL DATA No matter what I try


                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: CreditCard/Edit/5
        //public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        //{
        //    return View();
        //}

        // POST: CreditCard/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, IFormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add update logic here

                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: CreditCard/Delete/5
        //public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        //{
        //    return View();
        //}

        // POST: CreditCard/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, IFormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add delete logic here

                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the vue code:

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        CardVendor: '',
        CardNickname: '',
        CreditCardType: '',
        CardLimit: '',
        CardBalance: '',
        InterestRates: [
            {
                interestRate: '0.30',
                startDate: '1/1/2020',
                endDate: '6/30/2020'
            },
            {
                interestRate: '0.60',
                startDate: '7/1/2020',
                endDate: '12/31/2020'
            }
        ]
    },
    methods: {
        addInterestRate: function (event) {                   
            this.interestRates.push({});
        },
        removeInterestRate: function (event) {            
            this.interestRates.pop({});
        },    
        addCard: function (event) {
            //alert(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(app.$data)));
      
            axios
                .post('/CreditCard/Create', {
                    data: this.CardVendor                    
                }).then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }    

    }
})
```

Here is the View:

```html
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Add Credit Card";
}
<h1>
    Add Credit Card
</h1>
<div id="app">
    <!--Vue App Start-->
    <label>Credit Card Vendor Name:</label>
    <br />
    <input v-model="CardVendor" placeholder="[Enter Credit Card Vendor Name]" size="50">
    <br /><br />

    <label>Credit Card Nick Name:</label>
    <br />
    <input v-model="CardNickname" placeholder="[Enter Credit Card Nickname]" size="50">
    <br /><br />

    <label>Credit Card Type:</label>
    <br />
    <select v-model="CreditCardType">
        <option value="1">Visa</option>
        <option value="2">Mastercard</option>
        <option value="3">Discover</option>
        <option value="4">American Express</option>
        <option value="5">Other</option>
    </select>

    <br /><br />

    <label>Credit Card Credit Limit:</label>
    <br />
    <input v-model="CardLimit" placeholder="[Enter Credit Card Limit]" size="50">
    <br /><br />

    <label>Credit Card Credit Balance:</label>
    <br />
    <input v-model="CardBalance" placeholder="[Enter Credit Card Balance]" size="50">
    <br /><br />

    <label>Add Interest Rate(s):</label>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Interest Rate %</th>
                <th>Start Date</th>
                <th>End Date</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(item,index) in InterestRates">
                <td><input type="text" v-model="item.interestRate"></td>
                <td><input type="text" v-model="item.startDate"></td>
                <td><input type="text" v-model="item.endDate"></td>
                <td><button type="button" v-on:click="removeInterestRate(item)">Remove</button>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button v-on:click="addInterestRate">Add Interest</button>

    <br />
    <br />

    <button v-on:click="addCard">Add Card</button>

    <br />
    <br />
    <font color="gray">CardVendor-debug: {{ CardVendor }}</font><br />
    <font color="gray">CardNickname-debug: {{ CardNickname }}</font><br />
    <font color="gray">Creditcardtype-debug: {{ CreditCardType }}</font><br />
    <font color="gray">CardLimit-debug: {{ CardLimit }}</font><br />
    <font color="gray">CardBalance-debug: {{ CardBalance }}</font><br />
    
    <!--Vue App End-->
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/lib/vue/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/axios/axios.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/addcreditcard.js"></script>
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vue, you are sending an object like this:

```
{
    data: this.CardVendor                    
}
```

but your controller Create method takes just string input not an object and hence its NULL.

```
[HttpPost]        
public ActionResult Create([FromBody]String CardVendor)
```

**Fix**: (1) **Either** modify c# controller to take in an object instead of string. 
So, please modify your controller action to take in an object like below:

```
[HttpPost]        
public ActionResult Create([FromBody]CardVendorModel cardVendorModel)
```

and define a C# model as below:

```
public class CardVendorModel
{
    public string data {get; set;}
}
```

(2) **Or** modify Vue code to send a string to MVC controller action like below:

```
axios.post('/CreditCard/Create', 
  '\'' + this.CardVendor + '\'')
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: I went with the first option and it works great!! Thank you so much!! You saved me hours of headaches!

Comment: This is a great article that I found that talks exactly about what you are saying! https://adeyinkaseun.com/2017/07/28/post-data-from-vuejs-to-asp-net-core-using-axios/

Comment: The working code is published now to: https://github.com/encouragingapps/DebtRefresh

Comment: Glad that it helped. Also, thank you for the link. It indeed is nice one.